# Bokeh: Generating graphs in a loop, the output graph's file sizes keep increasing

Tags: python, pandas, graph, bokeh

I'm using bokeh to plot 100 graph files in a loop.

```
for k in files:
    # Read the log file data into a df.
    log_file_name = str(k) + ".csv" 
    logged_data = pd.read_csv("csv/"+log_file_name, parse_dates=["dttm_utc"], date_parser=dateparse)

    new_logged_data = logged_data.set_index("dttm_utc")
    mean_data = new_logged_data.resample("3D", how=[np.mean])

    # Extract the energy values and time stamps out into two ds.
    energy_data = mean_data["value"]["mean"]
    time_data = mean_data.index

    # Plotting
    output_file("csv/plots/" + log_file_name + ".html", title="Energy Consumption")

    p = figure(width=1600, height=350, x_axis_type="datetime")
    p.line(time_data, energy_data, color='navy', legend='energy')
    #p.circle(time_data, energy_data, size=2, color='navy', alpha=0.2, legend='energy')

    p.title = log_file_name + "   INDUSTRY: " + i + "   SUB-INDUSTRY: " + j)
    p.title_text_font_size = '10pt'
    p.legend.location = "top_left"
    p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0
    p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Energy (kWh)'
    p.ygrid.band_fill_color="olive"
    p.ygrid.band_fill_alpha = 0.1
    save(p)

    count += 1
    print str(count) + " " + log_file_name
```

What I'm noticing is that the size of every graph file is more than it's previous one (Please look at the Screenshot 1).

If regenerate all 100 graphs the file sizes are not same as the previous iteration (Screenshot 2).

A strange thing I have also noticed is that if I restart the kernel of my Jupyter notebook then the file sizes reset to the least (Screenshot 3), once again if I repeat regeneration of all 100 files they keep increasing.

The number of samples for generating these graphs is always same then why are file size different? Am I forgetting to do something, like closing the file? Any help!

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 2):

As of Bokeh `0.11.1` it is sometimes necessary to explicitly clear the output with the `reset_output` function:

```
from bokeh.plotting import reset_output
```

The in each iteration:

```
reset_output()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a propoer answer since it is unclear what you're suggesting. Please [write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and elaborate

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
```

Then before your plotting block where you have your output file, put in:

```
curdoc.clear()
```

This will clear off all of your previous graphs. I'm willing to bet if you look at any file after the first file, you have multiple plots. When I first started with Bokeh, it took me 3 hours of research to figure that out!